# Socket IO on connect race condition?

Tags: socket.io

I am working with socketio (1.2.0) currently and have discovered it seems like the client side `connect` event does not mean the connection is ready, has anyone else seen this issue or is there something I am missing?

I have a fairly large application that runs in the context of a google chrome extension; however I have pulled out the code to verify this is the issue.

Here is my client code (This works sometimes, not always):

```
var connection = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/myNamespace",
    {transport:"websocket", reconnection:false});
connection.on("connect",function(){
    connection.emit("myEvent",{"testKey":"testData"});
);
```

Here is my server code:

```
var namespace = io.of("/myNamespace");
namespace.on("connection",function(handshake) {
    auth.main(handshake , function(error , socket){
        socket.on("myEvent" , function(data){console.log("Event Data:",data);});
    }
}
```

If I change my client code to look like this, it works 100% of the time(would just rather not use it):

```
var connection = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/myNamespace",
    {transport:"websocket",reconnection:false});
connection.on("connect", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        connection.emit("myEvent",{"testKey":"testData"});
    },1000);
```

I have verified the event in the first example of client code is not getting emitted with a tcpdump and wireshark.

Any ideas if the socket may not be "ready" yet to be able to emit events due to a race condition?

Comment: Why are you using `reconnection: false`?  That means if the connection is lost, your data will stop flowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but the explanation is too long for a comment, so I'll put it in an answer.  I'm wondering if your auth is causing a delay and you have to wait for the auth to be done before your connection will really work properly.

What happens if, after the auth completes, you send a message to the client and when that message is received by the client, then (and only then because you know that auth is done) you send the data from the client?

Client:

```
var connection = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/myNamespace");
connection.on("ready", function(data) {
    console.log("Received ready");
    connection.emit("myEvent",{"testKey":"testData"});
});
connection.on("connect",function(){
    console.log("Received connect");
);
```

Server:

```
var namespace = io.of("/myNamespace");
namespace.on("connection",function(handshake) {
    auth.main(handshake , function(error , socket) {
        socket.emit("ready", true);
        socket.on("myEvent" , function(data){console.log("Event Data:",data);});
    }
}
```

---

It appears that you are doing authentication outside of the supported way to do auth so perhaps that is causing the timing issue because `socket.io` doesn't know about your auth so it sends the connect msg, but you're still doing your own auth.

You can see the recommended way to do auth integrated into the connection sequence with socket.io here: https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Comment: Thats an interesting problem. I tried that solution and it seems to work perfectly.  The reason I am not using the recommended way for auth is so that I can add information to the socket; which does not work how I wanted it to.  Thanks for your help